# Symfony 4 - Assets folder not found

Tags: symfony, assets, symfony4

According to [Symfony Best Practices](https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/web-assets.html),

```
Store your assets in the assets/ directory at the root of your project.
```

But currently, I don't have this folder created and if I create it, I got the error telling me that ressources can't be found.

I tried **composer require webassets** , but don't working.

Anyone have the solution ?

Regards

Comment: I also tried symfony/asset , but not creating it.

Comment: Better to update the question with additional information than use comments.  In any event, Symfony has been trying to move away from asset management.  I don't see any recipe for it though you should still be able to use the bundle from 3.4.  However you might try [Symfony Webpack Encore](https://symfony.com/blog/introducing-webpack-encore-for-asset-management)

Comment: And the [Asset Component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/asset.html) is still there. And [Linking to Assets](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating.html#linking-to-assets)

Answer (score 2):

Placing assets folder in root directory is best practice. Reason that root directory cannot be accessible from outside. You should try Symfony's Webpack Encore plugin. It compiles your minimized and compressed assets into public folder so they can never be shown as original.

If that is not fit your interest just put your whole assets folder into public directory.

Answer (score 0):

You try following command.

```
$ composer require encore
$ yarn install
```

May be good to refer to here.
http://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/installation.html

Comment: Don't forget to install Symfony Asset Component. https://github.com/symfony/webpack-encore/issues/173#issuecomment-334396606

Answer (score 0):

1. Enable the encore `composer require encore`
2. update yarn `yarn install`